# Importing to WordPress without losing page ranking and permalinks

Tags: xml, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have imported all of my blog posts from a different CMS to a local WordPress setup to test things out before going live. Here is the layout of the XML file containing posts from the old CMS:

```
<PublishingArticles>
    <ID></ID>
    <CategoryID></CategoryID>
    <AllowComments></AllowComments>
    <AllowPingback></AllowPingback>
    <Body></Body>
    <Categories></Categories>
    <ContentFormat></ContentFormat>
    <IsAppoved></IsAppoved>
    <IsPrivate></IsPrivate>
    <IsPublished></IsPublished>
    <Language></Language>
    <LastModified></LastModified>
    <ParentID></ParentID>
    <PermaLink>/home/year/month/day/id/blog-post-name.html</PermaLink>
    <Pos></Pos>
    <Posted></Posted>
    <Ratings></Ratings>
    <Slug></Slug>
    <Title></Title>
    <TotalReads></TotalReads>
    <TotalComments></TotalComments>
    <TotalVotes></TotalVotes>
    <UserName></UserName>
    <Version></Version>
</PublishingArticles>
```

I've had no problems so far importing the posts, so my next move is to make sure the old URL's are redirecting to the new URL's.

I used WP All Import to import the posts, but there was no option to save the permalink for redirection. I've now installed the Redirection plugin but the settings don't seem to do what I want it to do.

I would like to redirect all of the old permalinks to the new locations. Does anyone have any ideas about how to go about this? I've tried looking around on Redirection but I'm unsure if it's the right way to go about it.

My current thinking is that I should extract all the permalinks from the XML file and tell the Redirection plugin to apply these, seeing as the ID will also be imported from the XML file and used when imported to WordPress. I have no idea how to do this on a mass scale however as there are 1700~ posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this:

- You can structure your URLs in the WordPress similar to your previous CMS setup by going to `Settings > Permalinks`. This way WordPress will automatically generate new urls similar to your old urls and you won't even need to do the redirections.
- You can redirect all your old urls to the new ones via .htaccess file like this (as discussed in the chat below that the new URLs will be structured exactly like the old urls):

**Old Domain URL:** http://old-domain.com/home/year/month/day/id/blog-post-name.html

**New Domain URL:** http://new-domain.com/home/year/month/day/id/blog-post-name.html

Add this into your .htaccess file to redirect all old urls to new ones unchanged:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# Redirects Entire Old Domain URLs to New Domain Unchanged
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-domain.com$ [OR]    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the old URL structure can be seen in my original post. Ideally I would like to change this structure as it is not a good URL strucure, so in WP I would like to change it to something like: `/%category%/%post_id%/%postname%/` The problem is that I have 1700~ posts. The XML file I have for all the old posts has a `<permalink>` tag which contains its permalink, but I don't know how to tell WordPress that it should use this redirect these old URLs to the new one. I have played around with `Redirection` as I said in my post.

Comment: @germainelol Being an seo expert myself, I can assure you that SEO-wise both the old and your new URLs are alike and the new URL structure that you are suggesting won't make any difference at all. Therefore, I would suggest you to maintain your old URL structure for solving the redirection issue easily which is a much more important SEO issue.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I will look into how to make them better from an SEO point of view too when I finish this task. If I am to keep the URL structure the same, I think I would still need to redirect the old URLs because I noticed the old CMS incorrectly generated the URL for a lot of the posts. Anyway, do you have any idea how I would go about redirecting these old URLs (in the XML file) to the new URLs?

Comment: @germainelol I have updated the answer with the required .htaccess code to redirect all the old URLs to the new ones unchanged